# TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertFileExists() must be of the type string, null given,

Tags: php, laravel

I have written the following test in Laravel:

```
public function testUserCanUploadFile()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $user = $this->signIn();

        Storage::fake('public'); //Mock a disk
        $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('test.jpg'); //Upload a fake image.

        $assortmentAttributes = Assortment::factory()->raw(); // Use the assortment factory.
        $assortmentAttributes['image_path'] = $file; // Add a additional field in the assortment factory.
    
        $this->post(route('assortments.store'), $assortmentAttributes)->assertRedirect(); // Post the fields to the assortmentcontroller store method.
        //Storage::disk('public')->assertExists($file->hashName()); // Check if the field exists.
        $this->assertFileExists($user->image_path);
    }
```

I want to check if the file also exists in the database.
In practice, the file upload works just fine. My test however, does not.

When I run my test I get the following error:
`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertFileExists() must be of the type string, null given`

The field is not set on `->nullable()` in my migration. I also did `dd($user->image_path)`. This just returns `null`.

I also changed:
`$assortmentAttributes['image'] = $file; // Add a additional field in the assortment factory.`

To:
`$assortmentAttributes['image_path'] = $file; // Add a additional field in the assortment factory.`

To make sure the field name matches the field name in my assortment migration.
Does anyone know how I can make sure that the file is found in my database field, so that my test finally works?

The code in my store method in my controller:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image'); //request the file
            $fileName = md5_file($image . microtime()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //use md5 for security reasons and get the extension.
            $image->storeAs('', $fileName, 'public'); //store the file in the public folder disk.
        } 
        
         if ($request->wantsJson()) {
             return response([], 204);
        }
```

What `signIn()` does:

```
protected function signIn($user = null)
    {
        $user = $user ?: User::factory()->create();

        $this->actingAs($user);

        return $user;
    }
```

Greetings,

Parsa

Comment: please provide the controller method for this route and what `signIn` is doing

Comment: Hi @lagbox please read the question edit. I have provided that information as well now.

Comment: What is `$user->image_path` supposed to contain, and where in your controller is that value actually being set?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: where in the code is this image path saved to the user? I don't see that any where, based on that i would expect that field to be `null`

Answer (score 2):

Based on my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514215/typeerror-argument-1-passed-to-phpunit-framework-assertassertfileexists-mus/65553585?noredirect=1#comment115923200_65553585) you are creating a user of fly and it's not persisted so your endpoint `assortments.store` does not know anything about it. You are mixing different kinds of testing approaches.

There are a few issues you need to address:

1. Decide what kind of testing (unit/integration/functional) you are doing, based on this answer you can decide what to do next.
2. If it's unit testing, then you cannot make POST request, because unit-testing is about testing a single unit from a class (e.g.: one method)
3. If it's integration testing, then you can "integrate" systems around your service e.g.: you want to test that your "service" **foo** can call service **bar** using the latest Laravel
4. If it's functional testing (most complicated and expensive), you'll need to set up a "testing environment" will all dependencies as MySQL, Redis and etc.

**Probably the best way for you to tackle your specific problem**: you need to call an action which is responsible for "assortments.store" directly from your test omitting Laravel Http Stack

Your code MAY looks like:

```php
public function testUserCanUploadFile()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $user = $this->signIn();
        // saving fake storage into variable for later
        $storage = Storage::fake('public'); // Mock a disk 
        $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('test.jpg'); //Upload a fake image.

        $assortmentAttributes = Assortment::factory()->raw(); // Use the assortment factory.
        $assortmentAttributes['image_path'] = $file; // Add a additional field in the assortment factory.
        $assortmentAttributes['user'] = $user; // passing user with request to controller

        // init controller and pass fake "storage" as dependencies (that's probably you have it)
        $controller = new AssortmentStoreController($storage);
        $request = new Request($assortmentAttributes);
        $response = $controller->handleAction($request); // calling action
    
        // Assert your response

        // Assert your fake storage

        // Assert user image because it was changed by object reference.
        $this->assertFileExists($user->image_path);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg! What exactly do you mean with `assert your fake storage` and `assert your response`?

Comment: you can assert (check) that your file was put into your fake storage. assert response, since I've removed `assertRedirect` you can do it manually.

Comment: And what does the `$storage` and `$request` variable contain exactly?

Comment: `$storage` will contain result of `Storage::fake('public')`, `$request` is just a example if your action needs it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do `dd($user);`

Just after: `$user = $this->signIn();`

Probably you're getting wrong data in `user`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see exactly what your `User` model looks like, but I think you just need to pull the updated user back from the database. Your current `$user` variable will not contain the updated value because you haven't asked for it.

Try changing your assertion to:

```php
$this->assertFileExists($user->fresh()->image_path);
```

`fresh` will return a new instance of the model with the latest data from the database.

---

To update your user in your controller:

```php
$request->user()->update(['image_path' => $fileName]);
```

Comment: Hi, I have changed it to that code but I still receive the same error: `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertFileExists() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/tests/Feature/AssortmentTest.php on line 117`

Comment: if after `fresh` user does not have image_path, that could mean that you "post" request to `assortments.store` does not update User entity.

Comment: Noticed another thing your `signIn` is creating a user on the fly, therefore, it won't exist in the database and image_path won't be persisted, also it's unclear how "assortmentAttributes" are mapped to User, you only update an image without any reference to the current user.

Comment: As Oleg points out, and based on what you've since posted as in your controller, it looks like you're not updating your user, you're just storing the file.

Comment: Hmmm I see. So how would I go about updating my user when I am storing my files? @OlegAndreyev. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When `$user->image_path` is null, file does not exist. You will receive failed test results. So, I suggest one line where you verify `$user->image_path` value that is null or not.

```
$this->assertNotNull($user->image_path);
$this->assertFileExists($user->image_path);
```

Comment: @Parsa_237 If you still get the same error, tell me.

Comment: Hi, I know get: `Failed asserting that null is not null.`

Comment: In your `store` method, you just save file in `public` folder. But, you did not update `image_path` property of current user. I think that you need to check this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your controller you are checking
`($request->hasFile('image'))`
While in the test you are sending
`$assortmentAttributes['image_path'] = $file; // Add a additional field in the assortment factory.`

You should instead update the test to

`$assortmentAttributes['image'] = $file; // Add a additional field in the assortment factory.`